# closing all web pages on session time out

Tags: asp.net, webbrowser-control, session-timeout

When a session is timed out in asp.net application, we need to close all the web pages those are already opened by a user.

Each page has sign out link. When the user click on that link, the home page is redirected to that page.

In this case, the other opened pages also needs to be closed.

How can we do this?

Comment: I think you can redirect to your home page

Comment: you cant close all pages

Comment: The problem is the user thinking that their session ends. So left the other opened pages as it was with the data. Here we are wondering on data security.

Answer (score 1):

For all pages:

1. AJAX call back to server to check whether Session has expired.
2. Parse result from AJAX
3. If session ended then close window or redirect to logged out page.

Comment: Won't the AJAX call to the server keep the session alive, especially if it checks for the current session?

Comment: I agree with Razzie... But what if the AJAX calls a webservice... I'm a newbie to Webservice.. Will the webservice call run in the same session of the original page call... ??

Comment: then the session termination can be handled manually, to supplement the ASP.NET session termination.

Comment: AFAIK you can only set `EnableSession` on the web-method using the `WebMethod` attribute. If you enable it, the session will be kept alive. If you disable it, you don't know if the session's alive...

Answer (score 0):

On the second thought... we can use what @thephpdeveloper said, particularly when user signs out formally... (like clicking the signout button) Once After a formal Sign out happens...  Such Ajax Call back can be used, cause the session will be valid but there will not be any user... Using this we can signal the page and close the browser window

Answer (score 0):

As Razzie commented, doing an AJAX callback to the same web-application will keep the session alive. Using a web-service also won't solve the problem.

This solution avoids keeping the session alive:

- Store every session in the database. This could be done in the `Session_Start` event in the `Global.asax` or after the log-in.
- Delete timed-out sessions from the database in the `Session_End` event in your `Global.asax` file or after the log-out.
- Do a periodical AJAX callback to a **different** web-application, e.g. a web running on a sub-domain, to check in the database if the session still exists.

I suggest you use the SessionID to identify the sessions.